# To take away memories

Tags: verbs, lyrics

I'm writing a song and I'm having trouble with the verb **take away**.
I understand that **to take something away** means to remove it. But I have also seen that to take away memories can mean to take them with you.

Lyrics:

> *When it's time to spread my wings*
>   *Take away the memories*

I want to express "spread my wings (as in "leave and start a new chapter in my life") and take the memories with me".

Does it work, or does it mean the exact opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there is some ambiguity in "Take away the memories." It could sound like a plea, or an imperative, e.g., "Please God, take away my memories; make me memoryless."

This particular interpretation might be avoided if you add an "And":
"When it's time to spread my wings / And take away my memories." That makes it clearer that you are actively the one taking them.

If, however, adding a syllable isn't an option, "Take with me the memories" would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As it's written, I would understand you to mean **remove** memories, so, yes, the meaning isn't very clear.

How about:

*When it's time to spread my wings,*
*Take with me my memories...*